# If $X$ has Unif[0,2] distribution, then what is the density of $Y=X1_{(0,1)}(X)$

Tags: probability, statistics

If $X$ has Unif[0,2] distribution, then what is the density of $Y=X1_{(0,1)}(X)$? (1 is the indicator function)

What I have is that $Y=0$ with probability $P(1\le X\le 2)=F_X(2)-F_X(1)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $Y=X$ with probability $P(0<X<1)=\frac{1}{2}$, so the density of $Y$ is

$$f_Y(y)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1(y=0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1(0<y<1)}$$
Also, what is the dominating measure for this? Is it a joined density of a point mass and a Lebesgue measure?

Comment: One does not need $n$ random variables to ask a question about one only. Please rewrite.

Comment: Thanks, I've rewritten the question.

Comment: It doesn't have a density. Since Y has a positive probability of taking the value 0, which is a set of Lebesgue measure zero, it doesn't have an absolutely continuous distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X\ge 1$ then the indicator function becomees zero, so $Y=0$. That happens with probability one half. In the other case, $Y$ becomes uniform on $(0,1)$.  So the distribution of $Y$ is a mixture of a point mass and a uniform distribution, with mixture weights $(1/2, 1/2)$.

A dominating measure for this is the sum of Leb plus a point mass at zero.